# Loss function for an unsupervised neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am trying to use a neural network approach to fit a model based on two sets of data: the "before" set and the "after" set. The "after" set is the subset of "before" examples that have survived to a given point in time. The neural net tries to attribute survival probabilities `y` to entries `x`. This is an unsupervised task. 
For `N` observations in the "after" set, the loss function in this case is a log-likelihood based on the survival probabilities `y` of each datapoint `x`.

It writes:

```
loss = Sum[log[y],{x,{"after"}}]-N*Log[Sum[y,{x,"before"}]]
```

However, how can I define the loss function in that case, since it must collect all outputs from a given batch and combine them in non-additive way to be computed?